# JavaScript: Date arithmetics with german datestrings

Tags: javascript, string, date-arithmetic

I have a Problem to solve in JavaScript.

A textfield in a form has a german (short, but not too short) date: "22.12.2017" (Format: DD.MM.JJJJ).

After the User leaves the textfield, the date has to be checked if it is one year (365 days) shorter or bigger than the todays date.

I realy don't know how how to do that within the time-window my user gave me and need help from the specialists around here.

If someone knows a link to a code snippet please let me know.

Thanks alot.

konsti

Answer (score 1):

Let the variable `date` holds the field's value `22.12.2017` as a string:

```
// split the date into an array
date = date.split('.'); 

// turn the array into a Date object
date = new Date( date[2], date[1]-1, date[0] );

// today's date
today = new Date();

// timespan between date and today in milliseconds
timespan = Math.abs( date - today );

// check the timespan is not more than 365 days
does_fit = timespan < 365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000;
```

Of course you should check the entered date is valid and correctly formatted.

Usually you would do that after you split it into parts with `split`.

Comment: This will work, just be aware that leap years have 366 days, if it's relevant for your use.

Comment: @helb of course, you're right. The OP specifically asked about 365 days so I did go that way for simplicity.

Comment: Thank you verry much Paolo. That brings me forward.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Optional:* Check if the form field contains a date in the correct format: You can use the `.length` property and Regex for that
2. Extract the date parts from the string using `.slice()` and create a `Date` object using those slices.
3. Compare your newly created date object with today's date.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip. This optional check i've allready done but not with .slice(). I used .split(9 in an array. I checked if the entry is 10 chrs. length, has two dots and if the Day is smaller/greater than 01/31, the months is smaller/greater than 01/12 and the year is greater than 2025, just to be sure there is a serious entry.